# Asymptotically exact confidence interval

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, poisson-distribution, asymptotics

I am trying to answer the following question:

> [image: The Question is]

I have modeled it using a Poisson distribution, and from this calculated the Fisher information as $I(\lambda)= \frac{n}{\lambda}$.

Then, when I constructed the confidence interval, I used
$\lambda{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{nI(\lambda)}}}*z_{(1-\alpha/2)}$ for the lower bound. However, when I then plug in the numbers I get my confidence interval as $[2.98, 3.02]$ which seems too small. Where have I gone wrong? Should I do it differently?

Comment: Why did you use a Poisson to model a proportion?

Comment: Maybe consider the implications of word number 26.